# Xpath - get maximum attribute for each element

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

Given the following XML, what Xpath 2.0 query will get me the maximum date for each contact?  My goals ito find contacts who haven't been touched in 30 days.

```
<contacts>
  <contact>
    <name>james</name>
    <touch method='email' date='2002-02-04'>a</touch>
    <touch method='meeting' date='2010-02-04'>b</touch>
  </contact>
  <contact>
    <name>bob</name>
    <touch method='phone' date='2001-02-04'>y</touch>
    <touch method='email' date='2009-02-04'>d</touch>
  </contact>
  <contact>
    <name>cindy</name>
    <touch method='email' date='2012-02-04'>v</touch>
    <touch method='phone' date='2012-02-04'>h</touch>
  </contact>
  <contact>
    <name>john</name>
  </contact>
</contacts>
```

`max((//@date/xs:dateTime(.)))` will get me a single maximum date but I'm trying to get three dates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easier version.

You generally do not need to for-in-return for sequences of nodes, as / does the same.

```
/contacts/contact/max(.//@date/xs:dateTime(.))
```

and to find the contact before a limit:

```
/contacts/contact[max(.//@date/xs:dateTime(.)) < '2013-05-04']
```

Comment: Nice. For some reason I need to cast '2013-05-04T00:00:00' as a dateTime for it to work in my environment, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Use `for` as you want to get the maximum value for *each* contact

```xml
for $x in /contacts/contact return max($x//@date/xs:dateTime(.))
```

Comment: I need to get contacts who haven't been contacted after a certain date.  Taking your xpath above, I've come up with `for $x in //contact return max($x//@date/xs:dateTime(.))[. < '2013-05-04']`.  But then how do I get the name of the contact?